# Condición en Bucle for-each no afecta a los valores de su interior

Tags: html, xml, xpath

Buenas, estoy trabajando con en XML de Aemet y mi propio XSLT estoy realizando lo siguiente:

```
      <tr class="fondo-azul blanco centrado">

        <xsl:for-each select="prediccion/dia/prob_precipitacion//@periodo[(position() &lt;3)]">
            <xsl:if test=".='00-12'">
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="."/>h</td>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test=".='12-24'">
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="."/>h</td>
            </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>

      </tr>
```

Y me muestra esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Cuando yo esperaba que solo me mostrase el resultado de los 3 primeros días:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como aclaración el XML que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
<prediccion>
    <dia fecha="2017-05-31">
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="00-24"></prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="00-12"></prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="12-24"></prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="00-06"></prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="06-12"></prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="12-18"></prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="18-24">0</prob_precipitacion>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="00-24"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="00-12"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="12-24"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="00-06"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="06-12"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="12-18"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="18-24"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <estado_cielo periodo="00-24" descripcion=""></estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="00-12" descripcion=""></estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="12-24" descripcion=""></estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="00-06" descripcion=""></estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="06-12" descripcion=""></estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="12-18" descripcion=""></estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="18-24" descripcion="Poco nuboso">12</estado_cielo>
        <viento periodo="00-24">
            <direccion></direccion>
            <velocidad></velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="00-12">
            <direccion></direccion>
            <velocidad></velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="12-24">
            <direccion></direccion>
            <velocidad></velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="00-06">
            <direccion></direccion>
            <velocidad></velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="06-12">
            <direccion></direccion>
            <velocidad></velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="12-18">
            <direccion>N</direccion>
            <velocidad>10</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="18-24">
            <direccion>C</direccion>
            <velocidad>0</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <racha_max periodo="00-24"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="00-12"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="12-24"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="00-06"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="06-12"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="12-18"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="18-24"></racha_max>
        <temperatura>
            <maxima>23</maxima>
            <minima>14</minima>
            <dato hora="06"></dato>
            <dato hora="12"></dato>
            <dato hora="18">20</dato>
            <dato hora="24">16</dato>
        </temperatura>
        <sens_termica>
            <maxima>23</maxima>
            <minima>14</minima>
            <dato hora="06"></dato>
            <dato hora="12"></dato>
            <dato hora="18">20</dato>
            <dato hora="24">16</dato>
        </sens_termica>
        <humedad_relativa>
            <maxima>95</maxima>
            <minima>60</minima>
            <dato hora="06"></dato>
            <dato hora="12"></dato>
            <dato hora="18">70</dato>
            <dato hora="24">85</dato>
        </humedad_relativa>
        <uv_max>8</uv_max>
    </dia>
    <dia fecha="2017-06-01">
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="00-24">80</prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="00-12">15</prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="12-24">80</prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="00-06">0</prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="06-12">15</prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="12-18">70</prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="18-24">0</prob_precipitacion>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="00-24"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="00-12"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="12-24"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="00-06"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="06-12"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="12-18"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="18-24"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <estado_cielo periodo="00-24" descripcion="Intervalos nubosos con lluvia escasa">43</estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="00-12" descripcion="Intervalos nubosos">13</estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="12-24" descripcion="Intervalos nubosos con lluvia escasa">43</estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="00-06" descripcion="Poco nuboso">12n</estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="06-12" descripcion="Intervalos nubosos">13</estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="12-18" descripcion="Intervalos nubosos con lluvia escasa">43</estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="18-24" descripcion="Nuboso">14</estado_cielo>
        <viento periodo="00-24">
            <direccion>N</direccion>
            <velocidad>10</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="00-12">
            <direccion>N</direccion>
            <velocidad>10</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="12-24">
            <direccion>N</direccion>
            <velocidad>10</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="00-06">
            <direccion>C</direccion>
            <velocidad>0</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="06-12">
            <direccion>N</direccion>
            <velocidad>10</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="12-18">
            <direccion>N</direccion>
            <velocidad>10</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="18-24">
            <direccion>N</direccion>
            <velocidad>5</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <racha_max periodo="00-24"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="00-12"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="12-24"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="00-06"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="06-12"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="12-18"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="18-24"></racha_max>
        <temperatura>
            <maxima>23</maxima>
            <minima>15</minima>
            <dato hora="06">15</dato>
            <dato hora="12">23</dato>
            <dato hora="18">21</dato>
            <dato hora="24">17</dato>
        </temperatura>
        <sens_termica>
            <maxima>23</maxima>
            <minima>15</minima>
            <dato hora="06">15</dato>
            <dato hora="12">23</dato>
            <dato hora="18">21</dato>
            <dato hora="24">17</dato>
        </sens_termica>
        <humedad_relativa>
            <maxima>90</maxima>
            <minima>65</minima>
            <dato hora="06">85</dato>
            <dato hora="12">70</dato>
            <dato hora="18">75</dato>
            <dato hora="24">90</dato>
        </humedad_relativa>
        <uv_max>9</uv_max>
    </dia>
    <dia fecha="2017-06-02">
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="00-24">100</prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="00-12">90</prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="12-24">100</prob_precipitacion>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="00-24">2200</cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="00-12"></cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="12-24">2200</cota_nieve_prov>
        <estado_cielo periodo="00-24" descripcion="Cubierto con lluvia">26</estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="00-12" descripcion="Cubierto con lluvia">26</estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="12-24" descripcion="Cubierto con lluvia">26</estado_cielo>
        <viento periodo="00-24">
            <direccion>N</direccion>
            <velocidad>10</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="00-12">
            <direccion>N</direccion>
            <velocidad>10</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="12-24">
            <direccion>N</direccion>
            <velocidad>10</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <racha_max periodo="00-24"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="00-12"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="12-24"></racha_max>
        <temperatura>
            <maxima>18</maxima>
            <minima>14</minima>
        </temperatura>
        <sens_termica>
            <maxima>18</maxima>
            <minima>14</minima>
        </sens_termica>
        <humedad_relativa>
            <maxima>95</maxima>
            <minima>80</minima>
        </humedad_relativa>
        <uv_max>9</uv_max>
    </dia>
    <dia fecha="2017-06-03">
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="00-24">100</prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="00-12">100</prob_precipitacion>
        <prob_precipitacion periodo="12-24">90</prob_precipitacion>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="00-24">1900</cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="00-12">2000</cota_nieve_prov>
        <cota_nieve_prov periodo="12-24">1800</cota_nieve_prov>
        <estado_cielo periodo="00-24" descripcion="Cubierto con lluvia">26</estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="00-12" descripcion="Cubierto con lluvia">26</estado_cielo>
        <estado_cielo periodo="12-24" descripcion="Cubierto con lluvia">26</estado_cielo>
        <viento periodo="00-24">
            <direccion>N</direccion>
            <velocidad>10</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="00-12">
            <direccion>N</direccion>
            <velocidad>10</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <viento periodo="12-24">
            <direccion>N</direccion>
            <velocidad>10</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <racha_max periodo="00-24"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="00-12"></racha_max>
        <racha_max periodo="12-24"></racha_max>
        <temperatura>
            <maxima>15</maxima>
            <minima>12</minima>
        </temperatura>
        <sens_termica>
            <maxima>15</maxima>
            <minima>12</minima>
        </sens_termica>
        <humedad_relativa>
            <maxima>95</maxima>
            <minima>80</minima>
        </humedad_relativa>
        <uv_max>7</uv_max>
    </dia>
    <dia fecha="2017-06-04">
        <prob_precipitacion>95</prob_precipitacion>
        <cota_nieve_prov>1700</cota_nieve_prov>
        <estado_cielo descripcion="Nuboso con lluvia escasa">44</estado_cielo>
        <viento>
            <direccion>NO</direccion>
            <velocidad>10</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <racha_max></racha_max>
        <temperatura>
            <maxima>18</maxima>
            <minima>10</minima>
        </temperatura>
        <sens_termica>
            <maxima>18</maxima>
            <minima>10</minima>
        </sens_termica>
        <humedad_relativa>
            <maxima>80</maxima>
            <minima>55</minima>
        </humedad_relativa>
        <uv_max>7</uv_max>
    </dia>
    <dia fecha="2017-06-05">
        <prob_precipitacion>65</prob_precipitacion>
        <cota_nieve_prov>1900</cota_nieve_prov>
        <estado_cielo descripcion="Muy nuboso con lluvia">25</estado_cielo>
        <viento>
            <direccion>NO</direccion>
            <velocidad>10</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <racha_max></racha_max>
        <temperatura>
            <maxima>18</maxima>
            <minima>10</minima>
        </temperatura>
        <sens_termica>
            <maxima>18</maxima>
            <minima>10</minima>
        </sens_termica>
        <humedad_relativa>
            <maxima>90</maxima>
            <minima>60</minima>
        </humedad_relativa>
    </dia>
    <dia fecha="2017-06-06">
        <prob_precipitacion>60</prob_precipitacion>
        <cota_nieve_prov>2300</cota_nieve_prov>
        <estado_cielo descripcion="Intervalos nubosos con lluvia escasa">43</estado_cielo>
        <viento>
            <direccion>N</direccion>
            <velocidad>5</velocidad>
        </viento>
        <racha_max></racha_max>
        <temperatura>
            <maxima>23</maxima>
            <minima>9</minima>
        </temperatura>
        <sens_termica>
            <maxima>23</maxima>
            <minima>9</minima>
        </sens_termica>
        <humedad_relativa>
            <maxima>90</maxima>
            <minima>55</minima>
        </humedad_relativa>
    </dia>
</prediccion>
```

Cualquier ayuda seria de gran agrado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambia

```
<xsl:for-each select="prediccion/dia/prob_precipitacion//@periodo[(position() &lt;3)]">
```

a

```
<xsl:for-each select="(prediccion/dia/prob_precipitacion//@periodo)[position() &lt;3]">
```

Comment: Gracias me has salvado la vida!!! Al final puse    <xsl:for-each select="(prediccion/dia[position() &lt;4]/prob_precipitacion/@periodo)">